# Is it possible to change the animation speeds in Silverlight themes?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, themes, silverlight-toolkit

Is it possible to change the animation speeds that are used in the Silverlight toolkit themes?

Specifically, I like the look of the Expression Dark theme, however I feel that some of the animations it uses take too long and make it feel sluggish.

I'd like to be able to modify the animation speeds thru a setting, and be able to do so without having to copy the theme to my own and re styling the whole thing.  I'm guessing the answer to this is that its not possible, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to VS now, so I am just thinking out loud here. But I think you could create your own custom controls and derive from the controls you want to change. Then you could override OnApplyTemplate and hopefully find the animation elements you want to change in the visual tree. At that point you should be able to change their values (I think). But it would require a lot of code if you want to change many of the controls. And you would still need to look through the XAML of the templates to determine how to find them in OnApplyTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building your own theme from the Expression Dark theme. They are open source and available for modification.

Inside the Toolkit install you'll find the .Xaml for the theme; you can use that with ISM.